# Debugger in CPP-eclipse sometimes freezes

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-oxygen

I am trying to debug following source code using debugger of eclipse-oxygen for C/C++ Developers:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long int ll;
typedef vector<int> vi;
typedef vector<char> vc;
typedef pair<int, int> pi;
const int mod = 1e9 + 7;
const double EPS = 1e-9;
const int INF = 1 << 29;
#define mp make_pair
#define el putchar('\n')
#define sp putchar(' ')
#define Fill(a, val) memset(a, val, sizeof a)
#define all(a) a.begin(), a.end()
#define tr(a, it) for (typeof(a.begin()) it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it)
#define in(n) scanf("%d", &n)
#define inl(n) scanf("%I64d", &n)
#define out(n) printf("%d", n);
#define outl(n) printf("%I64d", n);

int const NN = 1e4 + 6;
pair<pi, int> p[NN];

class Matrix{
public:
    ll r;
    ll c;
    ll **a;
    Matrix(){
        r = 0;
        c = 0;
        init(0);
    }
    Matrix(ll _r, ll _c){
        r = _r;
        c = _c;
        init(0);
    }
    Matrix(ll _r, ll _c, ll val){
        r = _r;
        c = _c;
        init(val);
    }
    void init(ll val){
        a = new ll*[r];
        for(ll i=0;i<r;++i)
        a[i] = new ll[c];
        for(ll i=0;i<r;++i){
            for(ll j=0;j<c;++j)
                a[i][j] = val;
        }
    }
    Matrix I(int _r, int _c){
        Matrix ret = *new Matrix(_r, _c);
        ret.a[0][0] =  1;
        ret.a[1][1] =  1;
        ret.a[2][2] =  1;
        return ret;
    }
    Matrix operator + (Matrix m){
        Matrix* res = new Matrix(m.r, m.c);
        for(ll i=0;i<res->r;++i){
            for(ll j=0;j<res->c;++j){
                res->a[i][j] = (this->a[i][j] + m.a[i][j])%mod;
            }
        }
        return *res;
    }
    Matrix operator *(Matrix m){
        Matrix* res = new Matrix(this->r, m.c);
        for(ll i=0;i<this->r;++i){
            for(ll j=0;j<m.c;++j){
                ll sum = 0;
                for(ll k=0;k<m.r;++k){
                    sum = (sum + this->a[i][k]*m.a[k][j])%mod;
                }
                res->a[i][j] = sum;
            }
        }
        return *res;
    }
    Matrix operator ^(ll power){
        Matrix ret = I(this->r, this->c);
        Matrix sq = *this;
        while(power){
            if(power & 1ll){
                ret = (ret * sq);
            }
            power >>= 1ll;
            sq = (sq * sq);
        }
        return ret;
    }
    void display(){
        for(int i=0;i<r;++i){
            for(int j=0;j<c;++j){
                cout<<a[i][j]<<",";
            }el;
        }
    }
};

Matrix getCoefficientMatrix(bool isFirstRow, bool isSecondRow, bool isThirdRow){
    Matrix* ret = new Matrix(3, 3, 1);
    ret->a[0][2] = 0;
    ret->a[2][0] = 0;
    if(isFirstRow){
        for(int j=0;j<3;++j)
            ret->a[0][j] = 0;
    }
    if(isSecondRow){
        for(int j=0;j<3;++j)
            ret->a[1][j] = 0;
    }
    if(isThirdRow){
        for(int j=0;j<3;++j)
            ret->a[2][j] = 0;
    }
    return *ret;
}

int main(){
    int n, m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;++i){
        cin>>p[i].second>>p[i].first.first>>p[i].first.second;
    }
    set<ll> distinct;
    map<ll, vector<pair<ll, ll> > > queries;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;++i){
        distinct.insert(p[i].first.first);
        distinct.insert(p[i].first.second);
        queries[p[i].first.first].push_back(mp(p[i].second, 1));
        queries[p[i].first.second].push_back(mp(p[i].second, 2));
    }
    Matrix dp = *new Matrix(3ll, 1ll);
    bool isFirstRow = false;
    bool isSecondRow = false;
    bool isThirdRow = false;
    dp.a[1][0] = 1ll;
    ll mxCol;
    if(n == 0)
        mxCol = m - 1;
    else
        mxCol = (*distinct.begin()) - 1 - 1;
    dp = (getCoefficientMatrix(isFirstRow, isSecondRow, isThirdRow) ^ mxCol)*dp;
    tr(distinct, it){
        ll currentCol = *it;
        ll nextMaxCol = m;
        if(it != distinct.end()){
            ++it;
            nextMaxCol = (*it) - 1;
            --it;
        }
        tr(queries[currentCol], itt){
            ll currentRow = (*itt).first;
            ll status = (*itt).second;
            if(status == 1){
                if(currentRow == 1){
                    isFirstRow = true;
                }
                else if(currentRow == 2){
                    isSecondRow = true;
                }
                else{
                    isThirdRow = true;
                }
            }
        }
        dp = getCoefficientMatrix(isFirstRow, isSecondRow, isThirdRow)*dp;
        tr(queries[currentCol], itt){
            ll currentRow = (*itt).first;
            ll status = (*itt).second;
            if(status == 2){
                if(currentRow == 1){
                    isFirstRow = false;
                }
                else if(currentRow == 2){
                    isSecondRow = false;
                }
                else{
                    isThirdRow = false;
                }
            }
        }
        dp = (getCoefficientMatrix(isFirstRow,
                isSecondRow, isThirdRow)^(nextMaxCol-currentCol))*dp;
    }
    cout<<dp.a[1][0];el;
    return 0;
}
```

The input used is:

```
2 5
1 3 4
2 2 3
```

I have set a break point at the first line of the *main()* function.
On running the debugger it sometimes doesn't stop at the break point (and simply freezes), but sometimes it does for the same source code. I wonder if this is due to some internal eclipse bug or due to my source code. I tried restarting eclipse, creating a new project , uninstalling eclipse etc. But this still happens occasionally. Any suggestions?

Comment: Each time you return a value by dereferencing a pointer to a heap allocated `Matrix` object memory leakes.

Comment: ohh thanks man for the clue :)

Comment: You need to trash those macros, `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and stuff like that. Including the entire standard library will probably waste more time compiling the code than the time it takes to write the proper `#include`s. If you worry that you will waste time typing, you need to work on your typing speed, not abuse macros.